# How to create a phpmyadmin export without indexes

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1068

I am having a bit of trouble with importing a database from a phpMyAdmin export. If I export each table individually and import it into the new database everything works properly. But if I export the entire database I receive

> error 1068 multiple primary key defined.

After examining the dump it would appear that after the data is imported there is a section at the end of the dump which is called "Indexes for dumped tables". This index tries to recreate the already imported primary key which in turn causes the error.

I have researched for hours on error 1068 but nothing seems to address my situation. To me it would seem easiest to simply create the dump wiyhout the index tables at the end. But unfortunately I am unabe to workout the option to do this.

So my question is it possible to make phpmyadmin create a dump without these indexes? And if so how?

Comment: XD That's funny. Is there no way to create a dump without theses indexes?

Comment: atleast not from phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Thanx Dave, you were right. I figured it out.

Comment: You're welcome, could you add answer to this question, so that if any other person what to achieve this, he/she could get help.

Comment: I didn't actually figure it out, I just made the backup with mysqldump instead. I then imported the database with the mysql terminal. It worked without errors.